# Can psql commands be executed from Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, psql

I want to know whether psql commands be executed from an Application ?
For example I want to make use of \crosstabview functionality which psql provides. It is a great feature to have when viewing the reports.

I have an application which uses Ruby on Rails. I'm thinking whether I can run the \crosstabview from the application.

Comment: You can execute a command using `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(...)`. However, I don't know if executing `\crosstabview` works.

Comment: RocKhalil - thanks for the comment. No it doesn't work with ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(...)

Answer (score 1):

These are features of psql application only. There is no way to use them via database driver, be it ActiveRecord or anything else. That's just a different thing.

However, you can have table view using, for example, [table_view](https://github.com/arches/table_print) gem.

Answer (score 1):

## Can psql commands be executed from Rails application?

It can theoretically be done by running psql from ruby. Its just a really clunky solution.

The [`psql --command`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/app-psql.html) option only takes a single function name or a SQL string that is parsable by the database and which cannot use psql specific functions. Which means that you can run for example `%x{ psql --command "\\h"}` but not `\crosstableview` which needs input.

That leaves using [PTY](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.1/libdoc/pty/rdoc/PTY.html) to open an interactive session.

```
# example using PTY to connect to an interactive psql shell
require 'pty'
require 'expect'

PTY.spawn('psql') do |output, input, pid|
  output.expect /\=\#/ do
    input.puts '\\conninfo'
    output.each do |line|
      puts line
    end
  end
end
```

While possible there is a much better solution - use the `crosstab` function from the [`tablefunc` extension](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tablefunc.html) which can be used with `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute`.

Comment: the limitation I had with crosstab made me use crosstabview. The limitation of crosstab is that the value fields is dynamic in my case. I dont have pre-defined list of horizontal headers. I will have to think of any other approach. May be something like gem as other user suggested. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do this with "\ir" option provided by psql. By this option, you can run the commands written in a file. So put all commands that you want to run in CLI in a single file.

Now you just have to connect to psql and pass filename to "\i" option.

Example: I created a file "a.rb" and it inlcudes the following-

```
psql -h localhost -U postgres
\ir filename
```